# My brain isn't working. A word for...?

Tags: single-word-requests

someone who doesn't like or can't do physical activity. Or any activity really. 
Keep wanting to say 'inclined' but that isn't it, of course.

Comment: What about 'vegetate'? It describes a state of lifelessness while still alive.

Comment: If they cannot do the work they are *physically disabled*.

Comment: Maybe they are ***disinclined*** to physical activity.

Comment: maybe they are comfortably ***reclined*** in their chair.

Comment: But i think despite the lack of clues, @flamesquirrel has the answer.

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps 'sedentary'?

This usually suggests little or no physical activity, but seems to me to be used in situations where the the avoidance of physical activity is deliberate or at least the consequence of choice. This may not meet your requirement for an *inability* to do physical activity.

Answer (score 1):

What about an invalid. See definition - http://www.dictionary.com/browse/invalid?s=t